# Who wrote to stdout?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, stdout

I would like to know how to figure out which of the linked libraries wrote to stdout. I'm using Linux (Fedora).

Current examle: we are using [generated XML-Parser files](http://xmlplus.sourceforge.net/) which in turn use several shared libraries. One of these libraries writes the following string to stdout

```
XMLSchema::XmlElement::XmlElement(XMLSchema::Types::ElementCreateArgs)
XMLSchema::XmlElement::XmlElement(XMLSchema::Types::ElementCreateArgs)
XMLSchema::XmlElement::XmlElement(XMLSchema::Types::ElementCreateArgs)
...
```

This happens all the time and clutters the console output.

What is the simplest way to find out which of the linked libraries does this?
Is there a way to stop a linked library from writing to stdout?

Comment: Perhaps run the program in a debugger and set a breakpoint on `puts`, `printf` and `fprintf`?

Comment: @BillLynch: Or `write`, which is the system call all of these eventually have to use.

Comment: Just grep all the libs for those strings

Comment: Are you under UNIX or Windows ?

Comment: @Caduchon Fedora Linux

Comment: @AdrianMay Grep did the trick, thanks! Now I still hope to get rid of these outputs.

Comment: @Beginner Are you sure the lib write in std::cout and not in std::cerr ? On unix you can easily check that by redirecting your output in files like `./exe 1> cout.txt 2> cerr.txt`. If it is the case, then you can redirect only the stream of cerr in a file and avoid the noise.

Comment: @Caduchon yes, I am sure: after figuring out where the string was comming from I was also able to find the source for the lib. It has the following line: printf("XMLSchema::XmlElement::XmlElement(XMLSchema::Types::ElementCreateArgs)\n");

Comment: @Beginner next idea : check the doc of the xml-parser about a "log level". I think it's not possible to know who write in a stream, but as said Adrian May, if the string is in the code, you can see it when you use grep on the library files.

Comment: @Caduchon yes, that solved the problem. I am currently working on a patch for the library.

Comment: @AdrianMay I didn't know this would work. Thanks for the tip. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grep all the libs for those strings.

(I was asked in a comment to post this as an answer and not just a comment.)